# How to include files from SVN repository in maven project

Tags: maven, svn

I have a project named com.myorg.HelloWorld. It is a maven java project in IDEA.
I have got a SVN repository like http://urlsvn/svn/core, that contains

- /src/util_1.java
- /src/util_2.java
- /src/util_3.java

and

- /class/util_1.class
- /class/util_2.class
- /class/util_3.class

I want it automatically include/update 2 files (util_1.class, util_2.class) from SVN repository into my Maven project and use them in my project(import ...).

Comment: This is not how you do it. You build the `util` as a JAR and then use it as `<dependency>`.

Comment: But in SVN, util_XXX.java and util_XXX.class can be modified by other people. If I compile the JAR from the required util_XXX.class, then when change util_XXX.class in SVN, I will not see these changes and I will have to manually track the changes and rebuild the JAR every time. How to automate this в maven?

Comment: You usually do this by automatically building the JAR through a build system like Jenkins or GitHub.